# How to make a phone call and put it on speaker without changing the main application? Android

Tags: java, android

How can I make a phone call and put it on speaker via an application without changing to the Phone Application on Android?

Comment: Are you building your own custom ROM or Android hardware?

Comment: No, I am not. It's a mobile application.

Comment: An ordinary Android application can only make a phone call by using `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL`, the latter requiring the `CALL_PHONE` permission. Either of those will bring up an activity.